# Open a new browser window from an asp.net page AND output to it?

Tags: asp.net

How can I open a new browser tab in ASP.NET and write to it? I don't want to redirect to a page but I want to write/output the content directly from source.

Comment: A similar question with accepted answer and example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696680/how-to-write-javascript-to-a-separate-window

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use JavaScript to do this then - look into [window.open](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html). Once you open a new window, you can access its `document` object to write the contents of it programatically.