# Open XML content in another window, using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, dom

I understand I cannot save XML content to a local file, because of security restrictions. but is there a way I can show the XML content in another browser window, as

```
Window.Open(xmlString, . .. );
```

that would work the same as -

```
Window.Open(URL, . . .);
```

- I cannot use server-side language.
- I can use javaScript \ jQuery. (I already use them to create the XML)
- I can have a template XML file, near my HTML. Is there a way to display the template file and change its content ? almost the same as [window.open: is it possible open a new window with modify its DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192239/window-open-is-it-possible-open-a-new-window-with-modify-its-dom) or [How to write JavaScript to a separate window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696680/how-to-write-javascript-to-a-separate-window) but I need to change XML nodes, and not HTML.

EDIT 1: try using myXmlWindow.document.write(xmlString)

=> I tried the suggested code -

```
    var xmlString = xml2Str(xmlDocument);
    myXmlWindow = window.open();
    myXmlWindow.document.write(xmlString);
    myXmlWindow.focus();
```

but it does not display the whole XML content, just the intern node values. and the new window still display "Connecting..." as it did not finish loading the content (missing close tag ???)

maybe I need to tell it is XML content and not HTML ???

my xmlString :

```
<root><device1>Name</device1><device2/><device3><Temprature_1>23.5</Temprature_1><Temprature_2>23.4</Temprature_2><Temprature_3>23.4</Temprature_3><Temprature_4>23.3</Temprature_4><Temprature_5>23.2</Temprature_5></device3></root>
```

the displayed content:

```
Name23.523.423.423.323.2
```

EDIT 2: my code -

```
function xml2Str(xmlNode) {
   try {
      // Gecko- and Webkit-based browsers (Firefox, Chrome), Opera.
      return (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlNode);
  }
  catch (e) {
     try {
        // Internet Explorer.
        return xmlNode.xml;
     }
     catch (e) {
        //Other browsers without XML Serializer
        // alert('Xmlserializer not supported');
        return('Xmlserializer not supported');
     }
   }
   return false;
}


    function fShow_xml_in_win() {

        var xmlDocument = $.parseXML("<root/>");
        var dev1 = xmlDocument.createElement('device1');
        var dev2 = xmlDocument.createElement('device2');
        var dev3 = xmlDocument.createElement('device3');
        dev1.appendChild(xmlDocument.createTextNode('Name'));
        xmlDocument.documentElement.appendChild(dev1);
        xmlDocument.documentElement.appendChild(dev2);
        xmlDocument.documentElement.appendChild(dev3);

            var i;
            var xNode;
            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
              xNode = xmlDocument.createElement('Temprature_' + (i+1));
              xNode.appendChild(xmlDocument.createTextNode( "myVal " + ((i+1) * 10) ));
              dev3.appendChild(xNode);
            }

        var xmlString = xml2Str(xmlDocument);

        alert(xmlString);

        xmlString = "<?xml version='1.0' ?>" + xmlString;  // I do not know how to add this node using parseXML :(
        alert(xmlString);

        myXmlWindow = window.open();
        myXmlWindow.document.write(xmlString);
        myXmlWindow.document.close();  // !! EDIT 3
        myXmlWindow.focus();

            return false;
    }
```

EDIT 3: solved the "connecting..." problem

I just needed to add myXmlWindow.document.close();

Answer (score 1):

You can open a blank window and then write content to it as follows:

```
myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100')
myWindow.document.write(xmlString);
myWindow.focus()
```

You may need to do some work to format your xmlString, but I think this approach will do what you want. If your xmlString is formatted, try adding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

to the start of your string.

Comment: Try adding <?xml version="1.0" ?> to the start of your string.

Comment: I added it, but still the same results - only inner node values, and the page is not "done"

Answer (score 0):

My understanding from your post, are

1.(From your firts point)
 you get xml from somewhere which is not your control. My suggestion is why don't you get as JSON?

2.(From your second point)
 If those XML is created by you means, Why aren't you try to write those XML from reference?
 For example:

```
 var reference = window.open();
 reference.document.write(<some string goes here>)
```

3.(From your third point)
As per understanding from your second point. You can create xml. So why are you changing after write the document?

Note: Generally XML is used for Server-to-server communication, JSON is used for Server-to-client(browser) communication.

Comment: I need to jenerate XML and not JSON - client request. I can use a template, but I need to update it with current values. Please see my Edit 1

Comment: Why don't use "textarea". And you can control it easy by javascript. reference.document.write('<textarea><root><device1>Name</device1><device2/><device3><Temprature_1>23.5</Temprature_1><Temprature_2>23.4</Temprature_2><Temprature_3>23.4</Temprature_3><Temprature_4>23.3</Temprature_4><Temprature_5>23.2</Temprature_5></device3></root></textarea>')